# Google Cloud MLEngine Prediction Error 429

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I am getting my feet wet with Tensorflow and MLEngine.
Based on `faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017` I trained a model with custom data using the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

The exported model's size is 190.5MB.

Local prediction works fine. But MLEngine gives me the following error when using gcloud:

```
"error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Prediction server is out of memory, possibly because model size 
    is too big.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
 }
```

And the following error when using the [NodeJS client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client):

```
code: 429,
errors: 
 [ { message: 'Prediction server is out of memory, possibly because model size is too big.',
     domain: 'global',
     reason: 'rateLimitExceeded' } ] }
```

The images I am using for testing predictions are PNGs with dimensions of 700px*525px (365kb) and 373px*502px (90kb)

I am not sure how too proceed.
Is it expected that object detection requires more memory than MLEngine offers?
Is the model's size really the issue here and how can I improve on that?

Thanks for you help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [page in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/troubleshooting#http_status_codes) explaining how http status codes can be interpreted in the context of online prediction. In this particular case, the nodes running your model ran out of memory (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820754/9251751) answer to an older question by a googler working with the ML Engine). The suggested solutions would be reduce your model size and/or using a smaller batch size (by default set to [64 records per batch](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#predictioninput)). Considering that your model is already smaller than the [maximum 250 MB](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models#check_and_adjust_model_size), you might want to first consider the latter solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! At the moment my batch consist of just one instance though. Maybe the pipeline config from the models repo is just not suitable for use with MLEngine? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config

Comment: There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307275/9251751) older answer, can you make sure you've gone through the list shared there?

Comment: 1) error is consistent with this model 2) The ~190mb are the size of the saved_model directory 3) using `top` I can see python using over 3gb of memory when during `gcloud ml-engine local predict`

Comment: Typically a model of this size should not result in OOM. But: tensorflow does a lot of lazy initialization, so some OOMs won't be detected until the first request to initialize the data structure. It's rare, but it could be that a graph explodes in memory causing OOM. So, there's not enough info to tell for sure what's the root cause. At this point, I would suggest that you rerun everything and raise a private issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) with your project **number**, thus providing access to logs (note: I'm with GCP Support)

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued support! As soon as I got time I will deploy a memory hungry model based on faster rcnn / resnet101 again and raise a private issue. For now I trained another model with a different config (faster rcnn / inception v2) which stays well within the memory limit. I'll accept your answer, I think there is enough info here to work with for someone stumbling over this issue!